# Google Drive Internal Server Error when searching

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I get an error when searching with the q parameter:

php code:

```
$parameters['q'] = "title = 'hello'"; 
$children = $service->children->listChildren('root',$parameters);
```

returns:

> Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message
>   'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root/children?q=title%20%3D%20%27hello%27:
>   (500) Internal Error'

I think it's something to do with the quotes as it works if I search for 'trashed = false'

I'm using the latest api client checked out from:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/checkout

Comment: Could you try with the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.children.list?folderId=root&q=title+%253D+'hello'&_h=1&) and tell us if it fails too? Make sure to authorize the app by toggling the OAuth 2.0 button. Also, could you try with `$service->files->list(array('q' => "title = 'hello' AND root in parents"))`?

Comment: I think it might have been a transient issue, I tried it with the OAuth Playground and with a PHP application and it worked as expected in both cases.

Comment: $service->files->list(array('q' => "title = 'hello' AND root in parents")) fails with "Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title%20%3D%20%27hello%27%20AND%20root%20in%20parents: (400) Invalid Value'" - but works ok if I omit "AND root in parents"

Comment: not transient issue - still can recreate this

Comment: My bad, the query parameter should be `"title = 'hello' AND 'root' in parents"` (notice the quotes around `root`).

Comment: Errors: Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title%20%3D%20%27hello%27%20AND%20%27root%27%20in%20parents: (500) Internal Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried it again after all this time and it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same error message when you didn't ask for the right permissions. Use the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, not (only) `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`